# How to make expandable list for Windows10 Universal App?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10, uwp, universal, windows-10-universal

I am newbie to windows universal app development and I need an expadable list. In the past I did it with WPToolkit for Windows Phone 8 but I read that it is not available for UWP. I see [ExpanderRT](https://expanderview.codeplex.com) project and tried to use it but I couldn't be successfull. I add Shared project of ExpanderRT as an existing project to my solution and use as in the screenshot. Now I'm taking the namespace error.
[image]

I have a time limit. I need fast and easy working soluton for expandable list. Thank you all for your help.

[UPDATE]
I tried https://github.com/brendankowitz/ZeroProximity.Accordion as @Osman said. But I'm not sure if it is the right decision. Because I see the expandable list and it works but project build throw error as in the screenshot below. I install it via nuget. It wasn't installed in the first place. I run as a administrator and changed project.json 's Copy to Output Directory value to Copy always. Then it was installed.
So my questions; Is this error important? Will it create problems when I want to put the app on store? I don't know how to act to this error, please help!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/brendankowitz/ZeroProximity.Accordion

You can use the library given in the link above. I used it on our UWP project.It works great.

Hope this helps,

Osman

Comment: I think it does not have any importance,To ensure , create app package then test it via WACK tool. If it passed , you may continue with this library.